# Почему после округления перестал отображаться график?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, highcharts

Здравствуйте.

Готовлю массив данных для графика KPI

функция подготовки данных

```js
function culcJson() {
            var jsonObj = ${json_text};
            var newJSON=[];
var KPI=[];
                var jsonResult = [];
                var a = 0;
                do {
                    var value=jsonObj.SucceededCount[a].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE/(jsonObj.SucceededCount[a].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE+jsonObj.FailedCount[a].FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE)*100;
                    KPI.push(value);
                    a += 1;
                } while (a < jsonObj.FailedCount.length)
                return KPI;
            }
```

для графической части использую

```js
$(function () {
                var KPI=[];
                var jsonObj = ${json_text};
                if (jsonObj!=null){KPI=culcJson();}

                $('#container4').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '${TITLE}'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [<c:forEach var="row" items="${SCRIPT_FailedCount.rows}">"${row.DATE__CURRENT__CHECK}",</c:forEach>]
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        area: {
                            fillColor: {
                                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                                stops: [
                                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                                ]
                            },
                            marker: {
                                radius: 2
                            },
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            threshold: null
                        }
                    },

                    series: [
                        {
                            name: 'KPI',
                            data: KPI
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
```

Если оставить в таком виде как указано выше, то все OK.
График отображается, НО мне захотелось уменьшить до 2-х количество знаков после запятой у значений KPI.
простым toFixed(2)

```js
KPI.push(value.toFixed(2));
```

после этого график перестал отображаться.

Ошибок в консоли нет.

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: чисто интуитивно, вас не смущаешь что toFixed возвращает строку, а у вас было число? Может оно где-то внутри графика и тайпкастится, а может и нет.

Comment: догадывался, что проблема где-то в этом :-) да было число...

Comment: ну я не уверен что проблема в этом, надо отлаживаться по-хорошему. но как вариант стоит посмотреть

Comment: вобщем собака была зарыта именно в этом.

Comment: сейчас как полноценный ответ тогда оформлю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что метод `toFixed` возвращает строку, а не число.

```
var myNumber = 3.14159;
typeof(myNumber.toFixed(2)); // string
```

Видимо обратное преобразование типов на уровне компонента не выполняется, или выполняется криво.

Что делать?
**1).** Вместо использования toFixed округлить до нужной точности с помощью Math.round. Это самый корректный способ. [toFixed в некоторых случаях округляет математически неверно.](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#num-tofixed-precision) 
что-то вроде:

```
var roundedNumber = Math.round(myNumber * 100) / 100;
```

Math.round округляет целое число, поэтому мы умножаем-делим на 10*(нужное количество знаков).

**2).** Но если мы не боимся ошибиться на +-1 в последнем знаке, то можно воспользвоаться и toFixed, просто привести результат toFixed к числу.

```
var roundedNumber = +myNumber.toFixed(2);
```

или

```
var roundedNumber = parseFloat(myNumber.toFixed(2));
```